# All custom apps accessible through Lightning App Launcher failing with: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow...

Tags: lightning-experience

As of this morning, or possibly yesterday evening, any apps I try to access through the App Launcher in Lightning fail with the following error message:

> Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('https://na15.salesforce.com') does not match the recipient window's origin ('https://na15.lightning.force.com').
>
> - AuraAlohaFrameNavigator.js:6

I'm assuming this is a bug coming from Salesforce as it fails on *AuraAlohaFrameNavigator.js* and never reaches any of my logic.

I'm just wondering if anyone else is seeing this or does anyone know if Salesforce is addressing it?

Comment: Unfortunately, experiencing exactly the same thing. Looks like an cross-domain issue. Sucks that the new UI is causing such significant issues like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Salesforce has resolved the issue themselves.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: @crmprogdev but this is an answer, I asked _does anyone know if Salesforce is addressing it?_ and the answer is _yes they have_.

Comment: Your post was in the review queue. Rather than elaborating, you received the standard verbage. IMO, this should have simply been a comment. "Looks like" doesn't really tell us anything definitive. Salesforce didn't acknowledge to you there was an issue of some kind which they took action to resolve. If they had, and you stated as such, I'd have no issues with posting it as an answer.

Comment: @crmprogdev this has happened a few times with Lightning. It happened much more frequently when Salesforce1 was being rolled out. The entire platform breaks and starts working again without any acknowledgement from Salesforce. We contacted them and were simply told _we're looking into it_.